# Using enquo with infer package

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I'm using the infer package to run Chi-square tests, e.g.,

```
df %>%
   chisq_test(label ~ feature)
```

I'd like to put this into a function, so I can write:

```
my_chisq_function(df, label, feature)
```

I would normally do this by writing a function similar to this:

```
my_chisq_function = function(df, label, feature) {

  feature = enquo(feature)
  label = enquo(label)

  df %>%
    chisq_test(!!label ~ !!feature)

}
```

But when I run it:

```
my_chisq_function(df, cohort, gender)
```

I get an error:

```
Error: The response variable `!` cannot be found in this dataframe.The response variable `!label` cannot be found in this dataframe.
```

Any thoughts/suggestions on how to get this to work?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct a formula after converting to string

```
my_chisq_function <- function(df, label, feature) {
 feature <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(feature))
  label <- rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(label))

  df %>%

     infer::chisq_test(as.formula(stringr::str_c(label, feature, sep="~ ")))


 }

my_chisq_function(df, cohort, gender)
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `enexpr` with `expr` from `rlang`

```
my_chisq_function <- function(df, label, feature) {


  df %>%
       infer::chisq_test(rlang::expr(!! rlang::enexpr(label) ~
                  !! rlang::enexpr(feature)))



}
```

-testing

```
df1 <- mtcars
df1$carb <- as.factor(df1$carb)
df1$gear <- as.factor(df1$gear)
my_chisq_function(df1, carb, gear)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  statistic chisq_df p_value
#      <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>
#1      16.5       10  0.0857
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `substitute`

```r
my_chisq_function = function(df, label, feature) {

  expr = substitute(chisq_test(x = df, label ~ feature))
  eval(expr)

}


# test:
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(cyl = factor(cyl), am = factor(am)) 

my_chisq_function(mtcars2, cyl, am)
## A tibble: 1 x 3
#  statistic chisq_df p_value
#      <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>
#1      8.74        2  0.0126
```